# How do I use the Attachments form control to update a many records?

Tags: powerapps, power-automate, powerapps-canvas

Below is a sample of what I would like to achieve. Assume the collection filtered the records in the datasource as expected. How would I patch the targeted/filtered record to save the items within an attachment form control?

```
ForAll(
    collection,
    Patch(
        datasource,
        First(Filter(datasource, collection_col_name = 'RecordID')),
        {
            column1: DataCardValue2_5.SelectedDate
        //    Attachments: DataCardValue23.Attachments
        }
    )
)
```

I have tried 'formName.updates' but that only appends the backend database with the parent record independent of the collection.

I am expecting:

- upload "test1.png" and "test2.png" to a PowerApp Attachments Form Control.
- save attachments to a collection/array of related records

Answer (score 0):

You have nested your logic in a ForAll() function. However, in the second argument of Patch (where you specify the record to be updated) you are not referencing ThisRecord, so perhaps you are updating the same record multiple times.

Assuming that your collection is merely a filtered version of the data source (same field structure), you could replace the entire `First(Filter(...))` expression with simply `ThisRecord`.